Sum of cosines constant on an interval
Fix a non-degenerate interval $[a,b]\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with $a>1$ and a constant $c\neq 0$. For a fixed integer $n\ge 2$, consider the sum
$$ \sum_{1\le i < j \le n} \cos(cx^i - cx^j)  $$
I would like to claim that this function is not constant on $[a,b]$ (i.e. is never constant on an interval). This is easy for $n=2$, but I'm struggling to prove it in the general case (the cosines could, in principle, magically cancel each other, and I'm not sure how to argue that this cannot happen).

It is an analytic function on $\mathbb C,$ so if it is constant on an interval on the real line, it is constant on all of $\mathbb C.$ That requires some beginning complex analysis. But it lets you drop the "on an interval" description.

It seems like you might be able to use the power series formula for $\cos$ and look at only the cases where on of $i,j$ is $1$ to get the power series for this function has a non-zero coefficient for $x^2.$

Basically, use $\cos x=1-\frac{x^2}2+O(x^4),$ and get that your function is: $$1-x^2(n-1)+O(x^4).$$

No. $O(x^4)$ is meant for $x$ near $0$, so $x^2$ is not $0(x^4).$ @YvesDaoust that would be true if it meant for $x\to\infty.$

$\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}2+O(x^4)$ isn't true except near $0.$ It is certainly not true as $x\to\infty.$ @YvesDaoust

Thanks @ThomasAndrews, if you post this an answer I'll accept it!
